Datetime frequency selector in ReactJS/MUI
I'm trying to write a page (ReactJS, with Material UI) where a user can input a frequency for a certain task to be done. The user should be able to decide if the task should be done every:

day in a week (Monday, Tuesday ,... ) and its interval (second Tuesday, etc.)
specific date monthly/annually (every 3rd May, every 12th of a month, etc.)
specific month annually
specific daily/weekly interval (every day, every week, second week, etc.)

As trying to implement this myself meant writing a field on every field (a dropdown for day in a week, one input each for date and month frequency, a Datepicker for specific date, and such) and each of their validations, I was wondering, does this feature exist in a library somewhere? And if not, what would be the best way to implement such feature?
